# Python Request вход на сайт

Tags: python, requests, auth

Необходимо сделать вход на сайт. Пытаюсь сделать следующим образом:

```
import requests
 
login = '************'
password = '**********'

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'})
 

data = {'username': login, 'password': password}
URL = 'https://somesite/simplesaml/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?'
payload = {'username': login, 'password': password}
params = {'action': 'process'}

session = requests.session()
r = requests.post(URL, data=data,params=params, allow_redirects=True)
print (account.content)
print(cookies)
print(r.url)
```

Обнаружил что информацию о входе, сайт хранит в виде куки которое действительна пока работает браузер, но что делать с этой куки не знаю.
Информацию сайт получает в виде username/password, узнал это сделав вход и отлеживая состояния в консоли разработчика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как войти на сайт и получить информацию с него? (в идеале вообще запарсить, но это второстепенно)
Буду благодарен за

Comment: какой сайт если не секрет?

Comment: Сайт университета, он очень неюзабельный, хочу его парсить на материалы

Answer (score 1):

Sessions должна хранить сохранять полученные куки и использовать их для следующего запроса.
Отправляйте логин в сессии (а не просто так):

```
s = requests.Session()
s.post(URL,...)
```

и в этой же сессии посылайте дальше запросы на то что вам нужно:

```
s.get(new_url,...)
```

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#request-sessions